# Linux X11 multiple clients in a single session

Tags: linux, x11, x11-forwarding

x11 servers and clients can be connected via SSH tunnel.

I'm wondering if it possible to connect multiple clients within a single session.

Which means :

I'm trying to display a desktop at four different places with four diffrent computers. So first computer will display left-top, second will display right-top and so on.

So I can move around windows as if every monitors are connected at one place.

Comment: You can't move an X11 client application from one ssh machine to another...

Comment: So I might have to approach like vnc viewer perspective to achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Why can't you simply use `ssh -X` and move your windows to a conventional place on the screen (or perhaps configure your window manager to place windows according to their hosts)?

Comment: This would be done with DMX: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xdmx .

Comment: For example, DMX could provide multi monitor support using two desktop computers, each of which has a single monitor. Or, it could unify a 4 by 4 grid of monitors between 8 computers each with 2 monitors attached to them. DMX is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

You could try opening several *Xephyr* sessions, and then moving and resizing these to the desired geometry using *wmctrl* command. You can find something like this (for a completely different goal) in this [post](http://netpatia.blogspot.com/2009/06/multiseat-in-ubuntu-904.html).